# SDL: Calling SDL_CreateRenderer Segfaults

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, sdl-2

When I use Software Rendering in my SDL2 project, everything works as expected.
e.g when the code for creating a SDL_Renderer looks like this:

```
this->renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(this->window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_SOFTWARE);
```

When I use Hardware rendering, e.g when the code for creating a SDL_Renderer looks like this:

```
this->renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(this->window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
```

For some reason, calling SDL_UpdateWindowSurface results in a SEGFAULT. I call SDL_UpdateWindowSurface in a standard way:

```
// Update window surface
SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);
```

I know that the way my window is setup is correct, since running the program with a Software Rendering SDL_Renderer works just fine, and doesn't yield a SEGFAULT.

Does anybody have any idea what might be causing this? Has anybody experienced something like this before?

Comment: With this little code it's just a guessing game for us.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Apologies, I'll adjust my question once I'm home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SDL_GetWindowSurace](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetWindowSurface) documentation says **You may not combine this with 3D or the rendering API on this window.**. Either generate surface and update window surface yourself (and forget about hardware acceleration) or use SDL_Renderer and never touch window surface (it doesn't even exist for accelerated backend).